# How to update table in SqlOpenHelper?

Tags: android, mysql

In my application i have Table with a "**number**" as a **integer**:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE WORKS  = 
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + 
"(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"  
+ SOME_TEXT + " TEXT,"  
+ NUMBER + " INTEGER")";
```

now, i want to update or change that table
like that (see the "**number**"):

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE WORKS  = 
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + 
"(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"  
+ SOME_TEXT + " TEXT,"  
+ NUMBER + " REAL")";
```

"**real**" from "**integer**" without deleting the data from the database or without adding one more colum like: "**number2** + "**real**".
it's possible?

Comment: please change those caps. That is like shouting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't really need to. "Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class." [Source](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: I think you not understand me. i want to replace the "Integer" to "Real" but my application is on the market with a 30,000 users. i dont want to delete they data .just replace the "number" to "real"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I were you I whould add a column and set it to real
than during onUpgrade I would copy all the data from the int column to the real column.

it's the simplest solution...

Comment: I know that. but i want the easiest way.